# What does v7 mean in <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView> is this specific to an android version?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I used the above mentioned widget in my XML. However, I'm just seeing a normal list view and not a recycler view on android 5.1. Wanted to understand if the above mentioned widget is specific to a particular OS version?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html#api-versions

Comment: it means nothing and it is there just because historical reasons

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation on Android Support Libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html#api-versions):

> Some of the Support Library packages have package names to indicate
>   the minimum level of the API they originally supported, using a v#
>   notation, such as the support-v4 package. Starting with Support
>   Library version 26.0.0 (released in July 2017), the minimum supported
>   API level has changed to Android 4.0 (API level 14) for all support
>   library packages. For this reason, when working with any recent
>   release of the support library, you should not assume that the the v#
>   package notation indicates a minimum API support level. This change in
>   recent releases also means that library packages with the v4 and v7
>   are essentially equivalent in the minimum level of API they support.
>   For example, the support-v4 and the support-v7 package both support a
>   minimum API level of 14, for releases of the Support Library from
>   26.0.0 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

No this denotes the version of Android Libraries.

> These libraries provide specific feature sets and can be included in
>   your application independently from each other.

Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html)

`I'm just seeing a normal ListView`
Well a Recycler View is a modification to the classical ListView. In the Layout Editor it appears like that only.

Answer (score 0):

**v7** is just part of the package name, and refers to the version of the support library your project is using. There was an earlier version (v4), which was used with API version 4 or less (Android 1.6). Version 7 support library was a later version of the support library, which worked with newer versions of Android, and introduced new features.
Some information about it here

**http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html**